# How to compare two values in different rows AND different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have it currently working comparing two values on the same row but different columns but I need it to compare one value to the previous row.

For example:
I need to compare the column 'Close' of the row at index 0 to the column 'Open' of the row at index 1.

```
df['HigherLower'] = 'No Change'

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Open'] < row['Close'] :
        df['HigherLower'] = df['HigherLower'].replace(['No Change'],'Lower')
    else:
        df['HigherLower'] = df['HigherLower'].replace(['No Change'],'Higher')
```

Comment: please provide a minimal sample of the input data and the matching expected output (as text)

Comment: what is the machine leraning & data science aspect of your question?

Comment: I think the example here is a bit misleading because it does not match the explanation in the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [10, 20, 30], 'Close': [5, 25, 15]})

df['HigherLower'] = np.where(df['Open'].shift() < df['Close'], 'Lower', 'Higher')
print(df)

# Output:
   Open  Close HigherLower
0    10      5      Higher
1    20     25       Lower
2    30     15      Higher
```

Comment: "I need it to compare one value to the previous row."

Comment: Use `.shift()`. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Are you asking me? i dont think they get notified but it doesnt matter

Comment: Lol. I'm sorry. I believed you're the OP. So thanks to pointed me out :)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much :)